# How to modify row values in iteration

Tags: pandas

The row values are not changed in the following iteration:

```
>>> df
         species  population
panda       bear        1864
polar       bear       22000
koala  marsupial       80000
>>> for i, r in df.iterrows():
...     r['population']=r['population']*2
...
>>> df
         species  population
panda       bear        1864
polar       bear       22000
koala  marsupial       80000
```

Can anyone please show me how can I persist the changed values in the above iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) returns copies that are *disconnected* from your original (`df`).

> Jeff Reback: You should **NEVER** modify something you are iterating over.

Use [`pandas.Series.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) instead :

```
df["population"] = df["population"].mul(2)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

         species  population
panda       bear        3728
polar       bear       44000
koala  marsupial      160000
```